# how to operate the mathematical data on the first fields and assign the varibale linux

Tags: linux, math, field, lines, operation

I have a file contaning for just 2 numubers.  One number on eash line.

```
4.1865E+02
4.1766E+02
```

I know its something line    BHF = ($1 from line 1 - $1 from line 2 )
but can find the exact command.

How can I do a mathematical operation on them and save the result to a variable.

PS:  This was got using

```
sed  -i -e '/^$/d' nodout15  
sed -i -e  's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' nodout15  
awk ' {print $13} ' nodout15 > 15
mv 15 nodout15
sed  -i -e '/^$/d' nodout15  
sed -i -e  's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' nodout15  
sed  -n '/^[0-9]\{1\}/p' nodout15  > 15
mv 15 nodout15
tail -2 nodout15 > 15
mv 15 nodout15
```

After all this I have these two numbers and now I am not able to do some arithmatics.   If possible please tell me a short form to do it on the spot rather doing all this jugglary. Nodout is a file with different length of columns so I am only interested in 13th column.  Since all lines wont be in the daughter file so , empty lines deleted. Then only those lines to be taken starting with number. Then the last two lines, as they show the final state. The difference between them , will lead to a conditional statement. so I need to save it in a variable.

regards.

Comment: I have to think that your task would be easier solved with a higher-level language such as Ruby, Python, or Perl.

Comment: yes,  I can do it with java , or something else like matlab , but my program has to be in linux now.

Comment: But most Linux distributions have Perl, Python, Ruby, Ocaml, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### awk

```
$ BHF=`awk -v RS='' '{print $1-$2}' input.txt`
$ echo $BHF
0.99
```

#### bc

```
$ BHF=`cat input.txt | xargs printf '%f-%f\n' | bc`
$ echo $BHF
.990000
```

Comment: infact how how to parse to a variable?  like RS, How can I retrive the value from RS now.

Comment: I want to use like.       if RS>1   do {}  else do {}

Comment: @hamaskhan You can do whatever you like. It's your choice.

Comment: ya , thats ok  , but how to access this variable?